# Hyperscan scanning in too much time

Tags: c++, intel, signature

- I am using a database that has a ten million lines signature to match PCAP packages. I finished the code with c++. **It cost 100 seconds in matching one 200m PCAP package.**
- Well, as I know, someone finished the project **, and that cost only several seconds in matching one 200m PCAP package.**
- This is my steps:

1. all my patterns look like this:

```
    id:1258808
    pattern:\x06\x62\x68\x69\x66\x72\x69\x03\x63\x6F\x6D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 
    flag   :0
```

2. I use block mode.
3. func hs_scan()

```cpp
    for (size_t i = 0; i < packets.size(); ++i) {
            const std::string pkt = packets[i];
            err = hs_scan(database, pkt.c_str(), pkt.length(), 0,
                                     scratch, onMatch, &matchCount);
            if (err != HS_SUCCESS) {
                cerr << "ERROR: Unable to scan packet. Exiting." << endl;
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
```

I am wondering where is my problem, and how to short the run time?

Comment: All I can say is "this code looks fine, the problem is probably in hs_scan". How did you determine that it takes over a minute to scan through 200 megabytes? Are you sure you're not losing time in IO instead? Show your full code.

Comment: Looks like this could be parallel-fored with `std::for_each` and `std::execution::par`

Comment: What is a `PCAP`? Please provide some reference and a full [mre] ! Is your question related to Bioinformatics (e.g. COVID-19 pandemic) or to computer security? In october 2020 the widely known virus is called Covid-19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, the cause of the slow is because I mixed too many different patterns of flags in my database. So I split the pattern by different flags, and it works amazingly. Thank u guys.